# Design pattern for game implementation

Tags: design-patterns

Sorry for the generic title, if anyone after reading the below has a better one please change it.

I'm implementing a popular board game in python. One game feature includes five piles of tokens from which the player can take. I'm having trouble thinking of a good way to represent this in code. My current implementation looks somewhat like this (simplified for the post):

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        ...        
        self.tokens = num_tokens

class Player:
    def take_token(self, game):
        game.tokens[token] -= 1
        self.tokens[token] += 1
        return game  # the updated game instance
```

To me, this clearly seems like a terrible idea, because I'm passing the game state into `Player` just to manipulate it and then sending it back... there should be a much cleaner way to represent this. The problem is I like having the data stored under `self` for each object, as that seems a good way to bind the data to the object. Can someone help me identify the proper design pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        ...        
        self.tokens = num_tokens

    def give_token(self, token):
        if game.tokens[token] > 0:
           game.tokens[token] -= 1
           return 1
        else:
            return 0

class Player:
    def take_token(self, game):
        self.tokens[token] += game.give_token(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since its a design based question, I would say that you are giving more responsibility to a single class (Player in your case) than required. 
To write a more independent code, you must follow "Single Responsibility Principle"
You must write a loosely coupled code as suggested in previous answers.

There is a nice read in this link: https://medium.com/@severinperez/writing-flexible-code-with-the-single-responsibility-principle-b71c4f3f883f

Comment: Thanks for this. Curious what you think about the solution we came to (see my answer below).

Comment: @eykanal Yes you passed the responsibility to game class adhering tothis principle

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion, we decided that the best way to maintain encapsulation while keeping object ownership of relevant properties was through getters and setters with error propagation:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        ...        
        self.tokens = num_tokens

    def take_token(self):
        if self.tokens ≤ 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Trying to take from empty pile")
        self.tokens -= 1
        return True

class Player:
    def take_token(self, game):
        if game.take_token():
            self.tokens[token] += 1
```

This lets each object do its own accounting while maintaining proper boundaries for internal data.